# How to make columns into rows from same query in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

How to make columns `QuotedReal` and `Rated` as values in column `ActualStatus`

[image]

Can I pivot it somehow? Or append? 
Or should I create separate table and then UNION them together?
To make it look like this:

[image]

Please help.

The final goal is to prepare data to use `Horizontal Funnel by MAQ` chart, which look like this:

[image]

**UPDATE**
Alexis Olson thank you very much for your time and efforts. 
As per question 'Why'
I want to use Horizontal Funnel chart, but for this visual data have to look like this:

[image]

So that's the whole problem. I'm massaging data in SQL and in Power BI but still didn't solve the problem.
I know how to make this such data in SQL, but don't know how to achieve the same in DAX. For that I'll post another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do this (though I'm not entirely clear as to why).

Make a copy of your Table, then Group By no column and sum over the `QuotedReal` and `Rated` columns as seen below.

[image: Group By]

That should return two columns with the sums. Then unpivot both columns and change the names of the columns to `ActualStatus` and `CountActual`. You can then append this table to your original table.

The whole process looks like this in the M code:

```
let
    TableSource = <Source for your table goes here>,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(TableSource, {}, {{"QuotedReal", each List.Sum([QuotedReal]), type number}, {"Rated", each List.Sum([Rated]), type number}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.Unpivot(#"Grouped Rows", {"Rated", "QuotedReal"}, "ActualStatus", "CountActual"),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({TableSource, #"Unpivoted Columns"})
in
    #"Appended Query"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it tells me that ControlNo cannot be NULL because of one to many relationship. I updated question.

Comment: @Oleg You can add a custom column named `ControlNo` with the values you choose before appending it to your table if you need those for your relationship.